# Add new modules to running application NetBeans Platform

Tags: java, auto-update, netbeans-platform

I'm designing an application to be written with the NetBeans Platform Application Framework. The development is going to be made following the agile methodology. As characteristic with agile, once released the application, we're going to add new modules, beside updating the existing ones. I'm new at NetBeans Platform, and researching the web, I understand that when you deploy an app, the modules are configured to search into an "update center" for updates, but my question is if we add new modules, how can those modules been installed into an installed application?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add some news module to existing (running app) yust you can use silent update.